# Intellij fails to compile project. Error Resource Compiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

I have a MVC Java Spring project and it all worked good yesterday. Now, when I try to restart the project, to build it, it takes a long time to compile (over 30 minutes), while the other days it was like 5 mins max. Now, I have this error : http://collabedit.com/ay4ca . What should I do to make intellij compile faster and to solve this error?

Comment: Try with antivirus/firewall disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home, IDE process and project files are excluded from the scan.

Comment: Few days ago I faced same type of weird problems! A working projects was giving compiling errors(not this but another ones) next day!  It was resolved by simply restarting my pc!
You can try that too!

Comment: @user404, ok thanks. will do that

Answer (score 0):

About compile error try this one

1. Close IntelliJ
2. Delete C:\Users\USERNAME.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system directory
3. Start and Rebuild project.

About slow compile just try to increase Build Process heap size

Comment: Thank you! I already tried those 3 steps and now I am rebuilding the project, but it is again taking like forever... How much should the heap size be? Mine is now 3048 and still not working well... @wSvOgw

Comment: @LibrarySystem thats already more than needed. What's ur VM options? try to increase MaxMetaspaceSize, this resolve that problem for me. If it still slow, only support with cpu snapshot can help. As they say, every problem with perfomance can be unique